# Example 2, Sec. 29, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: A Cartesian Product of Finitely Many Locally Compact Spaces is Also Locally Compact

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

In Example 2, Sec. 29, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition, it has been shown that the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally compact. We can even state the following:

> Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be some finitely many topological spaces. If $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are all locally compact, then so is the product space $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Am I right?

Here is my attempted proof:

> Let us put
> $$
> X := \prod_{i=1}^n X_i = X_1 \times \cdots \times X_n. 
> $$

> Let $\mathbf{x} := \left( x_1, \ldots, x_n \right)$ be an arbitrary point of $X = \prod_{i=1}^n X_i$. We show that $X$ is locally compact at $\mathbf{x}$.

> For each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, as $x_i \in X_i$ and $X_i$ is locally compact, so in particular the space  $X_i$ is locally compact at the point  $x_i$, which implies that there exists a compact subspace $C_i$ of $X_i$ containing a neighborhood $U_i$ of $x_i$, that is, there exists a compact subspace $C_i$ of $X_i$ and also there exists an open set $U_i$ of $X_i$ such that
> $$
> x_i \in U_i \subset C_i. 
> $$

> Let us put
> $$
> C := \prod_{i=1}^n C_i = C_1 \times \cdots \times C_n
> $$
> and
> $$
> U := \prod_{i=1}^n U_i = U_1 \times \cdots \times U_n. 
> $$

> As $C_i$ is compact (regarded as a subspace of $X_i$) for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, so $C = \prod_{i=1}^n$ is also compact (regarded as a subspace of $X$), by virtue of Theorem 26.7 in Munkres.

> And as $U_i$ is open in $X_i$ for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, so $U = \prod_{i=1}^n U_i$ is also open in $X$; in fact $U$ is a basis set for the product topology on $X$. Refer to Sec. 15 in Munkres.

> Finally, as $U_i \subset C_i$ for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, so $U \subset C$ also.

> Thus $C$ is a compact subspace of $X$ containing the neighborhood $U$ of $\mathbf{x}$. Thus $X$ is locally compact at any point $\mathbf{x} \in X$.

> Hence $X = \prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ is locally compact, as required.

Is this proof correct and clear enough in each and every detail? Or, are there issues?